# How do I color clear resin after it has hardened?

Tags: painting, epoxy-resin, dyeing

I want to 3d print some Christmas decorations that are semi transparent, and different colors.

I could color the resin before I print, but as I want the decorations to be different colors this would mean multiple print runs and would create a lot of mess and waste.

Is there something that I could dip my finished and hardened decorations into, or paint on to them that would give an even and semi transparent effect?

I already have the clear resin ready to use.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for acrylic based paints like "Window Color" or similar transparent glass colors. They are relatively cheap and come in many different, vibrant colors. I strongly advice looking for viscous paints or gels. They are easier to apply, won't drip and create a more even coat than very liquid colors.

Here's one example:

[image]

I once tried painting a resin printed miniature, but the paint didn't stick well enough to be handled. However, if you put an even coat around the whole ornament, the dried paint itself should be stable enough (e.g. not rip or be pulled off too easily).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to special tools, you can also use some extraordinary things. You can use ink from ballpoint or gel pens, oil paints for artists, ink for polymer clay, alkyd paints, crayon leads

Comment: Hi Theo, welcome to Arts & Crafts! For clarification: what special tools are you talking about?